# How to pass schema name as parameter in stored procedure

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g

I need to pass a schema name as a parameter to a stored procedure. But I end up with error ORA00942: `table or view does not exist`. I googled a lot but didn't find any solution.

Actually in our application we are writing a Stored procedure (SP) in One schema and referring the same SP for all other schemas.

Consider I have to find the stock of an item in a different schema (1 schema for 1 client). Then

```
select * from abc.stock_table where itemid=xxx;
```

In this query I want to replace `abc` with different schema names.

Answer (score 0):

You need use Dynamic SQL, there are tons of material on Internet.
e.g. on [oracle website](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE query_invoice(
       month VARCHAR2, 
       year VARCHAR2) IS
    TYPE cur_typ IS REF CURSOR;
    c cur_typ;
    query_str VARCHAR2(200);
    inv_num NUMBER;
    inv_cust VARCHAR2(20);
    inv_amt NUMBER;
BEGIN
    query_str := 'SELECT num, cust, amt FROM inv_' || month ||'_'|| year 
      || ' WHERE invnum = :id';
    OPEN c FOR query_str USING inv_num;
    LOOP
        FETCH c INTO inv_num, inv_cust, inv_amt;
        EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
        -- process row here
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

It's imposible to change scheme in compiled PLSQL code on the fly.
You should use dynamic SQL instead.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm
But you must understand that this option has side effect - each time when you call dynamic sql it compiles again. So it's slower and more risky.

Answer (score 0):

Create public synonym for your object from different schema. Grant privilege on it.