# How to pass schema name as parameter in SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

As I have seen so far, people suggested using dynamic SQL.

For example:

[How to pass schema as parameter to a stored procedure in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436872/how-to-pass-schema-as-parameter-to-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server)

[How to pass schema name as parameter in stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108085/how-to-pass-schema-name-as-parameter-in-stored-procedure)

However, dynamic SQL has the risk of SQL injection. Hence, I want to know if there are any other safe alternatives?

Basically, this stored procedure that I am creating will be called at runtime. There will be 2 possible schemas to be passed in. And the table name will be passed in as well.

Something like below: (It does not work)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [EFM].[usp_readApexTable] 
    @SCHEMANAME VARCHAR(20) = NULL,
    @TABLENAME VARCHAR(100) = NULL
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT *  
    FROM [@SCHEMANAME].[@TABLENAME];
END
GO
```

This is just an example of READ action. My plan is to create for CRUD, which requires 4 different stored procedures.

Comment: Theoretically you could foresee all the different combinations and work from there. e.g. `IF @schema = 'dbo' BEGIN ... FROM [dbo].[myTable] END; IF @schema = 'test' BEGIN .. .FROM [test].[myTable] END`. This might work for 2 schemas, but if you need to plan all tables too then I doubt it's a workable solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `QUOTENAME` to avoid any SQL injection and build your dynamic query like the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [EFM].[usp_readApexTable] 
    @SCHEMANAME VARCHAR(20) = NULL,
    @TABLENAME VARCHAR(100) = NULL
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)=N'SELECT *  FROM '
          + QUOTENAME(@SCHEMANAME) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TABLENAME)
    EXEC (@SQL)
END
GO
```

**Note:** If you have any plan to add parameters also for your `WHERE` clause, in that case `QUOTENAME` will not help much, I suggest to to use `sp_executesql` by passing appropriate parameters used in `WHERE` clause.

Still you need to use `QUOTENAME` for schema and table name as `SQL` excepts it only as literal, you can't use variable names for table and schema.

For example.

```
  declare @sql nvarchar(max)
  set @sql = N'select * from ' + quotename(@SCHEMANAME ) + '.' +  quotename(@TABLENAME ) 
         + '  where (City = @City)' 
  exec sp_executesql 
    @sql, 
    N'@City nvarchar(50)',       
    @City
```

You can find more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Will QUOTENAME prevent SQL Injection?

Comment: @Henrix, for this case yes, for parameter in where clause, he need to move to sp_executesql with parameters. I have updated the answer for the same.

Comment: @PSK Thank you. I guess for my other operations (Create/Update/Delete), I have to use sp-executesql then...

Comment: Yes, as table name and schema name are expected as literal, so you cant pass them as parameter, you need to use quotename, for any other parameter you can use sp_executesql with parameter name

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [dynamic sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to do this operation

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [EFM].[usp_readApexTable] 
@SCHEMANAME VARCHAR(20) = NULL,
@TABLENAME VARCHAR(100) = NULL
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(MAX)
    SET @sqlCommand='SELECT *  FROM ['+@SCHEMANAME+'].['+@TABLENAME+'];'
    --Create Your Temp Table where you can set the records after executing the dynamic query
    CREATE TABLE #tmpTbl(
        Column1 [datatype]
        Column2 [datatype]
        .
        .
        ColumnN
    )
    INSERT INTO #tmpTbl EXEC sp_executesql  @sqlCommand --Copy data to #tmpTbl table
    SELECT * FROM #tmpTbl
    DROP TABLE #tmpTbl
END
GO
```

Comment: This approach is still vulnerable to SQL injection that the OP was concerned about. For example `EXEC usp_readApexTable @SCHEMANAME='dbo', @TABLENAME='sysobjects];DROP PROC usp_readApexTable;--'` will drop the procedure.

Comment: @Richardissimo thanks for the feedback, I'll update my answer soon.